# How can I change the height of those two floating buttons

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the height of those two buttons but cannot find the right way.
`height:50px;` seem not to be working.

### Here the CSS:

```
div.hscroll { 
    width: 550px; 
    height: 1000px; 
    overflow: scroll;
    top:35%;
    left:10%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.leftbutton{
    position:fixed;
    width:30px;
    top:35%;
    left:27%;
}

.rightbutton{
    position:fixed;
    width:20px;
    height:50px;
    top:35%;
    right:27%;
}
```

### And here the HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
var timer1;
function scrollDiv(divId, depl) {
   var scroll_container = document.getElementById(divId);
   scroll_container.scrollLeft -= depl;
   timer1 = setTimeout('scrollDiv("'+divId+'", '+depl+')', 10);
}
</script>

<div class="leftbutton";>
    <input type="button" value="«" style="height: 200px" onmousedown="scrollDiv('MyDiv', 10)" onmouseup="clearTimeout(timer1)" />
</div>

<div id="MyDiv" class="hscroll">Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_Comapare_

</div>
<div class="rightbutton";>
  <input type="button" value="»" style="height: 200px" onmousedown="scrollDiv('MyDiv', -10)" onmouseup="clearTimeout(timer1)" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working, but you've applied the CSS to the `<div>` containers rather than to the inputs themselves. Incidentally, you don't need semicolons after class assignments in HTML: `<div class="leftbutton";>`

Answer (score 1):

Inside your input tags, you have the following:

```
style="height: 200px"
```

Thats why the buttons are always 200px high. If you want them to be 50px then you can change it here. Alternatively you can remove the style attribute and set the height in the CSS using:

```
.rightbutton input {
    height: 50px;
}

.leftbutton input {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use the `button` element:

```
<div class="rightbutton";>
  <button value="»" />
</div>
```

And then you can define a class for the element `button` inside your `div`.

```
.rightbutton button, input {
  height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css, you are only changing the height of the , not the button.  In addition, you need to element for the button and change it from «

To change the height of both buttons, you can include this in your css:

```
<style>
button {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/S94ZB/)